# There is no overloaded method "OnMouseDown" with 0 parameters

Tags: .net, winforms, event-handling, delphi-prism

I am trying to set winform OnMouseDown event to a method I defined called SelectMouseDown.

The method is defined as follows:

```
method Maker.SelectMouseDown(Sender: Object; e: System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs);
```

and I am trying to do the following:

```
OnMouseDown += System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(@Self.SelectMouseDown);
```

The compiler throws the following error message: "There is no overloaded method "OnMouseDown" with 0 parameters."

What am I doing wrong? How do you set events during runtime?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you sure `OnMouseDown` is the *event*, and not a *method* (that invokes the `MouseDown` event)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `new`, and the event is named `MouseDown` as Marc Gravell pointed out:

```
MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(@Self.SelectMouseDown);
```

I don't know about Delphi, but in C# the compiler can create the delegate automatically:

```
MouseDown += @Self.SelectMouseDown;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works after I added the keyword new and changed onmousedown to just mousedown.